# Multi-item casrousel ng-repreat class="item active" Not working - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am able to load the data from JSON properly but not sure why below line is not working:

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="mCarousel in mCarousels">
```

I took it from [AngularJS ng-repeat with bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758858/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-bootstrap-carousel) link.
I can see only the second screen of multi carousel (I mean only 2nd objects of JSON).Below is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kitties for sale</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="./multiCarou/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="./multiCarou/theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS code from Bootply.com editor -->

</head>

<!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container" ng-app="baniyaApp" ng-controller="multiCarouselController">
        <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="mCarousel in mCarousels">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <!-- ITEM-->
                        <div class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="{{mCarousel.screen.view1.img}}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Kitty 1</h3>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="{{mCarousel.screen.view1.href}}">View details »</a></p> 
                        </div>  
                        <!-- ITEM-->

                        <!-- ITEM-->
                        <div class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="{{mCarousel.screen.view2.img}}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Kitty 2</h3>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="{{mCarousel.screen.view2.href}}">View details »</a></p> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- ITEM-->

                        <!-- ITEM-->
                        <div class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="{{mCarousel.screen.view3.img}}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Kitty 3</h3>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="{{mCarousel.screen.view3.href}}">View details »</a></p> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- ITEM-->

                        <!-- ITEM-->
                        <div class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="{{mCarousel.screen.view4.img}}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Kitty 4</h3>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="{{mCarousel.screen.view4.href}}">View details »</a></p> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- ITEM-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /INNER-->  
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>  
        </div>
</div><!-- /CONTAINER -->

    <script type='text/javascript' src="./multiCarou/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="./multiCarou/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./customAngular/kitty.js"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript jQuery code from Bootply.com editor  -->

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
          });
        });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

The JSON file has following data:-

```
{
"screen": {
    "view1":{
        "img" : "http://placekitten.com/605/300",
        "href": "http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view2":{
        "img": "http://placekitten.com/601/300",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view3":{
        "img":"http://placekitten.com/602/300",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view4":{
      "img":"http://placekitten.com/603/300",
      "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    }
},
"screen":{
    "view1":{
        "img" : "http://placekitten.com/604/300",
        "href": "http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view2":{
        "img": "http://placekitten.com/606/300",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view3":{
        "img":"http://placekitten.com/607/300",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view4":{
      "img":"http://placekitten.com/608/300",
      "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    }
  }
}
```

The kitty.js contains below controller and I can see **"Bingo"** as an alert:

```
var mainAngular = angular.module('baniyaApp', []);
mainAngular.controller('multiCarouselController',function($scope,$http){
var mcJson= "./customAngular/multiCarousel.json";
alert('Bingo');
$http.get(mcJson).success(function(response){
    $scope.mCarousels=response;
});
});
```

Can someone help me out on this. I know its some silly thing which I am missing out here but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: In my opinion I don't think you should mix imperative (jquery) with declarative (angularjs). Take a look at [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel). These are bootstrap components in angularjs.

Comment: @war1oc: Even after removing jquery code,it isn't working. The main problem is that I am not able to set class="item active" for the first div of multi-carousel. I have consulted below page for the above code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758858/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-bootstrap-carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. The Json was not properly formatted. Correct JOSN is:

```
[
{
"screen": {
    "view1":{
        "img" : "http://placekitten.com/609/300",
        "price": "Rs 100",
        "href": "http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view2":{
        "img": "http://placekitten.com/610/300",
        "price": "Rs 101",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view3":{
        "img":"http://placekitten.com/602/300",
        "price": "Rs 102",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view4":{
      "img":"http://placekitten.com/603/300",
      "price": "Rs 103",
      "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    }

}},{
"screen":{
    "view1":{
        "img" : "http://placekitten.com/601/300",
        "price": "Rs 104",
        "href": "http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view2":{
        "img": "http://placekitten.com/606/300",
        "price": "Rs 105",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view3":{
        "img":"http://placekitten.com/607/300",
        "price": "Rs 106",
        "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    },
    "view4":{
      "img":"http://placekitten.com/608/300",
      "price": "Rs 107",
      "href":"http://www.bootstraptor.com"
    }
}
}
]
```